# Rich Text Editing in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, rich-text-editor

I am using [this text editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/editor_in_windows_forms.aspx) for my windows forms application

This works great and is a wonderful control, however I am trying to accomplish one task: I wanted to insert a custom tag to the underlying html for eg if user clicks on a button on form I want to insert a tag <myTag>value</myTag>" at the cursor's position of text editor.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: This article was published in 2006; appears the author last responded to a question in 2007: you might want to search CodeProject for later articles on using a WebBrowser Control as an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys, Thanks for responses, following code solves the issue

```
        IHTMLTxtRange range = doc.selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
        range.pasteHTML(string.Format("<span>myTag</span>",range.text));
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
```

Answer (score 0):

get column and rows of cursor and put your HTML tag there. example if my cursor is blinking some where on the page try to get its X and Y (Rows and Columns).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the issue: Code Generation for the Property 'Body Background Color' failed. Error was: 'Property Accessor 'BodyBackgroundColor' on object editor 1 threw the following exception 'Input string was not in correct format'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).